# How to make something Scale from a fixed point

Tags: java, jogl

OK so I want to scale something in JoglGL using Java.
My code will scale something but I want it to be from my fixed point, which is my origin.. I read in the documentation that if I choose a fixed point to leave the same it should work, but each time I do it scales and moves from the center point ...Any ideas ?

public void scale(double sx, double sy)
    {

```
      vertices[0][0]=vertices[0][0]*sx;
      vertices[0][1]=vertices[0][1]*sy;
      vertices[1][0]=vertices[1][0]*sx;
      vertices[1][1]=vertices[1][1]*sy;
      vertices[2][0]=vertices[2][0]*sx;
      vertices[2][1]=vertices[2][1]*sy;
      vertices[3][0]=vertices[3][0]*sx;
      vertices[3][1]=vertices[3][1]*sy;


}
```

Comment: I also have a rotation method that will need the same but I presume If someone helps me with one, I can work that out easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet above, the scaling factor `sx` or `sy` is applied to all the vertices i.e. elements of the `vertices[][]` array. Skip the scaling factor to `vertices[0][0]`, and your problem should be resolved. :)